# Send logs in separate emails

Tags: nlog

When using the built-in [nlog Mail target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Mail-target), I am receiving multiple error logs grouped into one email.  There seems to be some kind of buffering occurring.

I want each log to be sent separately.

Example of my `log.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <targets async="true">
   <target
      xsi:type="Mail"
      name="email"
      subject="MyProject [${level:uppercase=true}]: ${message}"
      body="${message}"
      useSystemNetMailSettings="True"
      html="True"
      addNewLines="True"
      replaceNewlineWithBrTagInHtml="True"
      to="xyz@mydomain.co.za"
      from="no-reply@mydomain.co.za"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" level="Error" writeTo="email" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but this is impossible by default, and you can verify this by link: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Targets/MailTarget.cs#L282-L289.

But you always can create own NLog target https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/How-to-write-a-Target, based on MailTarget.